# Cross-platform Push API

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, push-notification, windows-phone

Is there any Push Notification API valid for Android, iOS and Windows Phone?

Parse works wonders with Android and iOS, and I can access data on WP, but has no WP push functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure Toolkit supports all 4 platforms.

[Android](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-android)

[Windows Phone](http://watwp.codeplex.com/)

[iOS](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios)

[Windows 8](http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/)

Not sure how practical this is for your use cases.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/05/windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios/). It links to other tutorials and screencasts which may be helpful to you. **Note that post is from 2011, which may a bit out of date by now.**

Comment: I want users to be able to send push notifications to their friends just like WhatsApp or Gtalk does.

Comment: Yes, I think it can be achieved. I've updated the answer to include a tutorial post for you to get started.

Comment: And yes, they support Windows 8 as well..